# InMobi Does not show any ads

Tags: android, ads, general-network-error, inmobi

I want to implement InMobi ads in my android application.

I have download the InMobi SDK and trying to show ads using sample app.

I have a **valid APP_ID** generated from InMobi server and following is the code i have( i am using sample app from INMobi SDK)

```
<com.inmobi.androidsdk.IMAdView
        android:id="@+id/imAdview"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        adSize="15"
        appId="14c9c64f24004a18ab1c6c718aa07eac" />
```

And in Activity:

```
mIMAdInterstitial = new IMAdInterstitial(this,"4028cba631d63df10131e1d3818b00cc");
```

but whenever i run the app i get one of the following error-

1)`NETWORK_ERROR`
2)`INVALID_APP_ID`

I do have Internet connection on my device.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Raju from the InMobi team here.
I just had a quick look at your app integrations. All you would need to do is to complete your App verification process. This would ensure the activation of your app on our network and you would start to receive ads.

Do write in to helpdesk@inmobi.com in case you continue to face issues.

Also, the InMobi diagnostics tool is a nifty way to identify issues around your integration. You could read more here:
http://www.inmobi.com/helpcenter/publisher-help/integration/how-to-set-up-publisher-diagnostics/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Inmobi has a very poor documentation