# Inmobi interstitial ads are showing blank screen with close button

Tags: android, ads, interstitial, inmobi

I am using Inmobi Interstitial Ad for one of my app. The ad is loading and displaying but it shows black screen with close button at top right corner.

[image: Blank Interstitial screen]

I have used following dependencies:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "...."
    ....
    multiDexEnabled true
    ....
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.inmobi.monetization:inmobi-ads:7.2.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

The interstitial is showing and all its listener callback are called.

Comment: What are you seeing in the callback when the ad is loaded? Are there any internal logs you are seeing?

Comment: In onAdLoadSucceeded callback I just logged the message and it is showing. And onAdLoadFailed callback is not called. No unexpected internal log.

Comment: So you are initializing and loading an ad correctly, but none show up? Have you made any special placements? Have you configured what needs to be in regard to InMobi? Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080231/inmobi-does-not-show-any-ads)?

Comment: Yes, ad is loading correctly but nothing shows up. I have just using only one Interstitial ad. Your link is for IOS.

Comment: Look again, the link is for ANDROID. [Another Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160497/inmobi-ads-does-not-show-up-on-android)

Comment: I have followed official link for interstitial ads -> https://support.inmobi.com/monetize/android-guidelines/interstitial-ads-for-android/

Comment: Contact InMobi and get assistance from them.

Comment: Hi, are you still facing this issue? If yes then please try again with the latest version of InMobiSdk and if the issue still persists then please let me know with the SDK version

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am using the AdMob directly  https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial